# Bootstrap CDN still being referenced in subtheme, turned off

Tags: theming

These are the setting in my .info for my subtheme:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; Stylesheets
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

stylesheets[all][] = css/style.css


; For information on choosing the desired method, please read the Drupal
; Bootstrap sub-theme "how-to" documentation:
; https://drupal.org/node/1978010

;----------------------------------
; METHOD 1: Bootstrap Source Files
;----------------------------------

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; Scripts
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; scripts[] = 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js'
scripts[] = 'bootstrap/js/affix.js'
scripts[] = 'bootstrap/js/alert.js'
scripts[] = 'bootstrap/js/button.js'
scripts[] = 'bootstrap/js/carousel.js'
scripts[] = 'bootstrap/js/collapse.js'
scripts[] = 'bootstrap/js/dropdown.js'
scripts[] = 'bootstrap/js/modal.js'
scripts[] = 'bootstrap/js/tooltip.js'
scripts[] = 'bootstrap/js/popover.js'
scripts[] = 'bootstrap/js/scrollspy.js'
scripts[] = 'bootstrap/js/tab.js'
scripts[] = 'bootstrap/js/transition.js'

; Disable BootstrapCDN if using Bootstrap source files in your sub-theme.
settings[bootstrap_cdn] = ''
```

When I view source I'm seeing this:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="all" />
```

Where is that coming from? Unless I've misread the settings above should have removed that. Several cache clears and it's still there.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't downloaded the bootstrap source files then the CDN will still load I believe. Once you download and place bootstrap inside of your subtheme then the bootstrap source files should load then. The docs mention this but I don't think it's very obvious but you have to download bootstrap and compile the styles.css file from styles.less and that should include your bootstrap styles. So if that file doesn't exist that may be the issue. Or bootstrap just not being there all together. It's been a while since I setup from scratch, I use the dev version and have drush setup everything now.

Comment: I do have the bootstrap source files downloaded to my subtheme, I have been using less to compile the source to *css/style.css*. Which is exactly why I was asking this question.

Comment: So all of the JS files are loading? The ones listed in your info file from above? Also, do you have the Bootstrap base theme turned off in Drupal, only your subtheme should be turned on when doing that. What version of Bootstrap are you using (the Drupal theme)?

Comment: The JS files are loading. The Bootstrap theme is turned off. I am using the 7.x-3.0 version of the Drupal Bootstrap Theme.

Comment: I would recommend upgrading to [beta2](https://www.drupal.org/node/2312697) or the [dev](https://www.drupal.org/node/1840986) version. I know that the recommended version says use 7.x-3.0 but the release date on that version was 2013-Nov-17 and beta2 is 2014-Jul-30. I've used beta2 and dev and I have never had this issue. You can also try uninstalling the themes just incase the variables table has been corrupted by updating procedures. Besides that I would probably need to see your site or chat with you a little more to see exactly what is happening.